# how to communicate between MATLAB and Visual C++ window form?

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, c++-cli, matlab-deployment

First of all, I am new to visual C++. I have a simple window form Visual C++ program which display circles on the form. I have a MATLAB program which will determine the locations of the circles and the number of circles should be on the window form. My question is how I can make them talk to each other?

Can I use dll? However, is it possible to make window form as dll?
Even if I have a window form dll, how I can send data from MATLAB to the window form?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/) to compile your MATLAB program into a .NET assembly